# How do I implement SelectionSort and InsertionSort on a linked list in Python?

Tags: python, linked-list, insertion-sort, selection-sort

I've implemented a Linked List class and I have a selectionSort and insertionSort function created that works on regular lists. I need to get selectionSort and insertionSort to work on linked lists, but I'm not sure where to even start, if I'm being honest.

Here's my linked list class:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next = None

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def setData(self,newdata):
        self.data = newdata

    def setNext(self, newnext):
        self.next = newnext

class unorderedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.head == None

    def add(self, item):
        temp = Node(item)
        temp.setNext(self.head)
        self.head = temp

    def length(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while current != None:
            count = count + 1
            current = current.getNext()

        return count

    def search(self, item):
        current = self.head
        found = False
        while current != None and not found:
            if current.getData() == item:
                found = True
            else:
                current = current.getNext()

        return found

    def remove(self, item):
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        found = False
        while not found:
            if current.getData() == item:
                found = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.getNext()

        if previous == None:
            self.head = current.getNext()
        else:
            previous.setNext(current.getNext()
```

Here's my code for selectionSort and insertionSort. They work just fine on regular lists, but I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out where to start to get them to work on a linkedlist (unordered list).

```
def selectionSort(alist):
    for fillslot in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
            positionOfMax = 0
            for location in range(1,fillslot+1):
                    if alist[location]>alist[positionOfMax]:
                            positionOfMax = location

            temp = alist[fillslot]
            alist[fillslot] = alist[positionOfMax]
            alist[positionOfMax] = temp

def insertionSort(alist):
    for index in range(1,len(alist)):

            currentvalue = alist[index]
            position = index

            while position>0 and alist[position-1]>currentvalue:
                    alist[position] = alist[position-1]
                    position = position-1

            alist[position] = currentvalue
```

Any suggestions/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to implement `insertionSort`, The code is readable. `SelectionSort` should be similar, try to implement it.

```
def insertionSort(h):
    if h == None:
        return None
    #Make the first node the start of the sorted list.
    sortedList= h
    h=h.next
    sortedList.next= None
    while h != None:
        curr= h
        h=h.next
        if curr.data<sortedList.data:
            #Advance the nodes
            curr.next= sortedList
            sortedList= curr
        else: 
            #Search list for correct position of current.
            search= sortedList
            while search.next!= None and curr.data > search.next.data:
                search= search.next
            #current goes after search.
            curr.next= search.next
            search.next= curr
    return sortedList

def printList(d):
    s=''
    while d:
        s+=str(d.data)+"->"
        d=d.next
    print s[:-2]

l= unorderedList()
l.add(10)
l.add(12)
l.add(1)
l.add(4)
h= l.head
printList(h)

result= insertionSort(l.head)
d= result
printList(d)
```

Output:

```
4->1->12->10
1->4->10->12
```

Comment: Awesome. I ran your code and it worked perfectly. 

I'll try to get selection sort next - this should be very helpful!

Comment: So, for the selection sort... I will just go through each node's data and if the current node's data is larger than the previous nodes, then that one will be set to a variable, such as largest. And it will stay as this variable until one of the next nodes is larger, then largest will change.

And then once it gets to the end of the list, largest will swap places with the last item (which, once I'm to the end of the list, should be the current node). 

Just trying to kind of think it through before I try coding it! @Taha