# Bubble sort in linked list. How do I make it sort by artist name?

Tags: python, bubble-sort

I want to sort the result by the artist name but it doesn't work. I get  `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'artistName'` error.

Here is my linked list. I add music with the music id, music name and artist name, and the linked list prints them out. I want to sort the linked list by the artist name in alphabetical order but my code doesn't seem to be working.

Can someone help me fix the bubble sort `sortByArtistError()` because I think now my code is for numbers but how do I make it arrange by alphabets and specifically the artist name?

Comment: The sample shown code hasn't implemented a method sortByArtistName(), or it is not shown here.

Comment: sorry forget to add added now

Comment: q = p.artistName -- q is a string now. What is 'q.artistName' supposed to mean?

Comment: And why make a new list when your can use ```list``` and sort it with the standard ```sort/sorted```?

Comment: cant use buoilt in lists

Comment: Your class has a method and a data member both named `next`.

Comment: Looks like a few classmates are asking about the same homework: [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54216505/9225671) and [question3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54216994/9225671)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to make a simple comment, but check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337414/python-implementation-of-mergesort-for-linked-list-doesnt-work). 
You should implement one of the sorting algorithms for your linked list, in the above linked answer you can see a Merge Sort implementation. Of course use the artist's name to compare the elements.

Edit: and [here is an insertion sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705235/how-do-i-implement-selectionsort-and-insertionsort-on-a-linked-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing because you try to use the name `next` in different contexts. Generally, it is not recommended to use keywords as object names. Also, you should take a closer look at how to implement an iterator protocol, using the corresponding dunder methods. It seems to me that you missed something there.

That being said, I came up with some code that is cleaner. It certainly is not optimal, but for the sake of readability you could use it as a starting point for some further studies.

For the node class, I replaced your getter and setter methods with a property object. This way you can access your variables like attributes, but behind the scenes the corresponding getters and setters are called. This saves a lot of typing.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, newData=None, nextNode=None):
        self.data = newData
        self.nxt  = nextNode

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data

    @data.setter
    def data(self, newData):
        self._data = newData

    @property
    def nxt(self):
        return self._nxt

    @nxt.setter
    def nxt(self, newNode):
        self._nxt = newNode
```

This remained untouched:

```
class Music :
    def __init__(self, id, musicName, artistName):
        self.id = id
        self.musicName = musicName
        self.artistName = artistName
    #defining how the string is displayed
    def __repr__(self):
        #adds in and formats the id, musicName, and artistName added to the Music collection
        return f'Music ID: {self.id}\nMusic Name: {self.musicName}\nArtist Name: {self.artistName}\n'
```

This did not. To be able to iterate over the linked list, you need the `__iter__` and `__next__` dunder methods. This can be used afterwards for the `iteritems` function which in turn can be used for the displaying of the list.

For the requested bubble sort, the credit goes to [this github repo](https://github.com/alicepham/python-singly-linked-list-sorting-algos/blob/master/A4_Q2_V9.py), which I merely adapted for the use in this context. I did not check if this is the fastest implementation, but it works.

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head  = None
        self.size = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        self.pointer = self.head
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.pointer is None:
            raise StopIteration
        curr, self.pointer = self.pointer, self.pointer.nxt
        return curr

    def get_size(self):
        return self.size

    def iteritems(self):
        for pos, node in enumerate(self):
            yield pos, node

    def addMusicToFront(self, newData):
        newNode = Node(newData, self.head)
        self.head = newNode
        self.size += 1

    def displayMusic(self):
        for _, node in self.iteritems():
            print(node.data)

    def sortByArtistName(self):
        sorted = False
        count = 0

        while not sorted:
            sorted = True
            prev = self.head
            curr = self.head.nxt

            while curr is not None:
                if prev.data.artistName > curr.data.artistName:
                    sorted = False
                    prev.data, curr.data = curr.data, prev.data
                    count += 1
                prev = curr
                curr = curr.nxt

MusicList = LinkedList()

MusicList.addMusicToFront(Music(1, "walkingdead", "beter"))
MusicList.addMusicToFront(Music(2, "pokemon", "albert"))
MusicList.addMusicToFront(Music(3, "power ranger", "dylan"))
MusicList.addMusicToFront(Music(4, "man", "carry"))

MusicList.sortByArtistName()
MusicList.displayMusic()
```

On my machine (using Python 3.6), this produces the following output:

```
Music ID: 2
Music Name: pokemon
Artist Name: albert

Music ID: 1
Music Name: walkingdead
Artist Name: beter

Music ID: 4
Music Name: man
Artist Name: carry

Music ID: 3
Music Name: power ranger
Artist Name: dylan
```